# A smooth plane is: $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$. A light ray hits the plane along the direction $(−1,−1,0)$. What's the normalized direction of the reflection.

Tags: linear-algebra

A smooth plane is described by the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$. A light ray hits the plane along the direction $(−1,−1,0)$. Find the normalized direction of the reflection. Enter the third component of the direction.

My solution (normalized): (0.66, 0.66, 0.35)

I'm pretty sure I have to normalize this. Can somebody please confirm my answer for me? I am unsure if I am correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is wrong.  The reflected ray will be in the direction given by
$$
\vec{r} = \vec{d} - 2 \, \text{proj}_{\vec{n}}\vec{d}
$$
where $\vec{d}$ is the direction of the incident ray, $\vec{n}$ is a normal to the plane and $\text{proj}_{\vec{n}}\vec{d}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec{d}$ on $\vec{n}$.
$$
\vec{r} = (-1,-1,0) - 2 \frac{(-1,-1,0)\cdot (1,1,1)}{(1,1,1)\cdot (1,1,1)}(1,1,1)
     =\left(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{4}{3}\right)
$$
so $\vec{r}$ normalized is
$$
\left(\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2}},\frac{4}{3\sqrt{2}}\right)
$$